# Use virtual protected factory methods to mock objects created within a class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, mstest, rhino-mocks

Rhino Mocks is tightly coupled with the design pattern of using dependency injection and constructor injection, but I typically don't follow the dependency-injection paradigm and don't like to re-architect my solution just for my test tool.

Take this scenario:

```
class MyClass{
    public void MyMethod(...){
      var x = new Something(...);
      x.A();
      x.B();
      x.C();
    }
}
```

Would it be quite typical and acceptable to instead do the following, since this is not a case where I would generally wish to inject the dependency - it can be considered part of `MyClass`' behaviour/logic.

```
class MyClass{
    public void MyMethod(...){
      var x = NewSomething(...);
      x.A();
      x.B();
      x.C();
    }
    virtual protected Something NewSomething(...){
      return new Something(...);
    }
}
```

Now I can (I think) extend `MyClass` either as a concrete class in my test project, or using Rhino... right? Is this a)correct b)a reasonably sensible, commonplace way of doing things?

Another approach I can see other than DI could be that I actually have a `ClassFactory` class in my project which creates all instances as needed; then I find a way to mock/stub that in my tests. But this seems 'smelly' to me, though I'm aware it is a pattern some people use.

Comment: What is `Something` here? It would certainly be more flexible if you accepted some sort of SomethingFactory (just a `Func<Something>` for example) in your constructor... basically your prod code is still tightly coupled to `Something` at the moment... I'd try to start thinking about this as a dependency.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah this would remove the problem but I'm not sold on wholesale DI. Let's not have that discussion here(!) but thanks for pointing out the alternative approach, it's certainly valid.

Comment: Well this is an odd question then - the "reasonableness" of your approach is surely relative to how reasonable other approaches are - but you're not willing to discuss those. If you're just asking "Would this code work" then the answer is "yes" but you could have tried that yourself...

Comment: @JonSkeet No I'm asking if my pattern is commonly employed rather than just being technically possible. I haven't said I'm not willing to discuss other approaches - your suggestion is welcome, I just don't prefer to go that particular route unless it is widely accepted best practice that DI is the 'right way' to develop software. I've tried to re-word slightly my question

Comment: Well at least part of that depends on the nature of `Something`, which is why I asked about it. Personally I'd *generally* prefer DI, but introducing DI into a non-DI application may be more effort than it's worth just for this one thing, and this could be something which doesn't feel like a regular dependency, but you only need to fake for one very specific, unusual reason. In other words, this is very context-sensitive, and you haven't provided much context.

Comment: Fair enough, good points.

Comment: Writing `var x = new Something(<some input data>)` is just basic object-oriented programming, and shouldn't be abandoned just to work around the limitations of some mocking library. The alternative proposed by @JonSkeet almost inevitably leads to replacing OO code (with true objects which encapsulate both state and behavior) with procedural code where some classes are dumb data holders while others are just a bunch of stateless procedures (and usually singletons, instantiated through DI, factories, or Service Locators). I would say avoid mocking, go for integration testing instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this quite a few times when trying to make legacy code more testable, although it really likes to come back and bite you later.

Basically, mocks/fakes/testdoubles are your enemy. You should hate them and avoid them (Edit note: I'm not saying don't use them, I'm saying use them only when you HAVE to). It all follows from the paradigm that all code is bad code, and we should write as little code as necessary to complete the task. Having a bunch of test doubles overriding virtual methods makes your code very rigid. It makes it really painful to change a method signature, even if your production code only invokes the method in a single place, because your test doubles will also break. It also makes it painful to later on clean up the mess and actually inject the dependency (and yes, I would argue injecting stuff is Objectively Better(tm)).

What it comes down to is basically: Yes, doing this will make your code more testable, but without any of the benefits you usually get by testing. You wn't get better design, you'll have rigid code etc.

I won't really point any fingers though, since I like I said have used this on occasion just to get a test up to see if something works. It can be a temporary solution that is "good enough", but my final answer is "probably don't if you can at all avoid it (and still have tested code)".

Answer (score 0):

You would be sacrificing the Single Responsability Pattern (SRP) with the method that you're suggesting, and arguably making your code harder to read, understand and maintain, there's a smell right there, before we even reach the talking about tests.

If you plan to run tests, and at the same time not follow [SOLID principles](http://www.davesquared.net/2009/01/introduction-to-solid-principles-of-oo.html) , then where are you saving on time, readability, or agility? (I honestly would love to know).

What the DI principle allows you to do is to run your tests completely in isolation from your dependencies, which is exactly what you want to be doing.

The SOLID principles of OOP have many good arguments going for them, but I'm always open to learn and be wrong, but I must say, I may have been blinded by several years of SOLID code, and tens of thousands of green unit tests securing my projects.

Comment: It is smelly but I'd say rearchitecting my entire codebase to fit a test tool is much _more_ smelly. I also don't want to make my classes harder to _use_ in return for making them easier to _test_, that seems backwards to me!

Comment: I hear you. Re-architecting a monolith is never done in one single-pass operation. HOWEVER, nothing prevents you in doing it vertically, pipe by pipe. remember the SOLID principles are there to make code easier to read and understand. You may think it more convenient to have the classes have dependencies to other classes, but in the long run, it comes and bites you in the back. If your class NewSomething needs to change, then you'll be forced to implement that change everywhere you use it. By then you no longer have a smell, but a foul stench :)